# Create behavior in yii2

Tags: yii2, behavior

I am using Advanced Template in Yii 2. I want to create behavior for user id, so I made folder in `common\components\behavior` and created one class,

```
class UidBehavior extends Behavior
{

    public function encryptUid($id)
    {
        $id = md5($id);
        return $this->$id;
    }
}
```

then in user.php =>

```
 'mybehavior' => [
     'class' => 'common\components\behavior\UidBehavior',
     'encryptUid' => 'id'
 ],
```

but error has occurred which is

> Setting unknown property: common\components\behavior\UidBehavior::encryptUid

can any one help me ?

Comment: [Create custom behavior](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-behaviors.html)

Comment: Take a look at how [Yii handles class properties](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-properties.html). Mainly, getters and setters.

Answer (score 0):

You try to init `encryptUid` property on User.php, Where that is not exist, You can rewrite code like this then all thing work fine:

```
class UidBehavior extends Behavior
{
  public $encryptUid;
  public function encryptUid($id)
   {
    $encryptUid = md5($encryptUid);
    return $this->$encryptUid;
   }
}
```

Check [Refer Link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-behaviors.html)